# TOTP issues in c# with same server as code generator and validator

Tags: c#, one-time-password, totp

I am trying to implement a time based OTP in my project where code generation and code validation will be done by same server. My whole requirement is to generate a OTP which should be valid for some time (configurable) and then send it to user email, with an option to resend the password to user's email.

I can understand once we generate a code for a particular secret key with a timestep, for that particular timestep it will generate same code for same key. but the problem in using this approach is Let's say timestep is 5 mins, a code is generated and valid for 5 mins. Now after 6 min, if I again send a code, then new code will only be valid for next 4 mins instead of 5 mins, since it was generated once previous code was expired.

ideally it should be valid for 5 mins from the time request is raised by user for the OTP.

Comment: Why is the expiration based on *last expiry* instead of *new request time*?

Comment: Also, is there any sample code you can share? There's not really enough here to help you.

Comment: @CoolBots: thats how this library works, based on last expiry, not last request

Comment: I am referring this code for my code generation, but instead of Google Auth, using my same server to generate verify the code.
 
var totp = new Totp(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("secretKey"));
var code = totp.ComputeTotp();
 
Console.WriteLine(code);

Verify : 
 
var totp = new Totp(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("secretKey"));

    bool valid = totp.VerifyTotp(inputCode, out long timeStepMatched,
      VerificationWindow.RfcSpecifiedNetworkDelay);
}

Comment: there is also a recommendation to match the TOTP with previous and next time frame's TOTP

Comment: @CoolBots: reference code 
https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/using-time-based-one-time-passwords-for-two-factor-authentication/

Comment: @Kristian: Are you referring to Verification window ? 
I think with that my previous 2 codes will be valid at once

Comment: it's okay because it also accounts for out of sync device time

Comment: @Kristian: Verification window only takes into account single or double steps i.e. couple of seconds at max, not more than that.